# VB.Net- How to get most recently created files in folder/How to get 10 most recent files from folder

Tags: vb.net

I searched for 2 days trying to find the answer for how to do this in VB.net. I found multiple answers for C#, but the syntax was off and I couldn't fixture it out, until I found [this](https://forum.uipath.com/t/find-latest-file-in-a-folder-with-respect-to-date-created/25289/13) which worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```
'Newest first, oldest last
Dim filesByCreateDate = New DirectoryInfo("Folder to Search").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).Take(10).ToArray

'Newest File
Dim newestFile = New DirectoryInfo("Folder to Search").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).First

'Oldest File
Dim oldestFile = New DirectoryInfo("Folder to Search").GetFiles().OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).First
```

Comment: You are doing things a rather odd way there. If you want `FileInfo` objects then why not use a `DirectoryInfo` in the first place, i.e. `Dim tenNewestFiles = New DirectoryInfo("folder path here").GetFiles().OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).Take(10)`? If you're not going to use a `DirectoryInfo` then don;t use `FileInfo` objects either, i.e. `Dim tenNewestFiles = Directory.GetFiles("folder path here").OrderBy(Function(s) File.GetCreationTime(s)).Take(10)`.

Comment: Also, I can't see that there's ever a reason to use `Take(1)` over `FirstOrDefault` or `First`.

Comment: Thank you for proving the rule about posting the wrong answer to get the correct answer!
I was doing things that way because I don't actually know what I'm doing and that was the first thing I found that worked, but I like your answers better, though